# Using ng-animate-ref with asynchronous data

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, angularjs-ng-resource

I have an angular app that uses `$resource` to load data into the views. I used ngAnimate's `ng-animate-ref` to transition an image from one view to another. This worked fine when the data was hardcoded into the controller, but when I use `$resource` or `$http`, the data takes a little longer to load and therefore there is no identifier in the `ng-animate-ref` directive to help link the two images together. I figure I need to do either one of two things:

1. Don't let the new view render until the content has loaded
   or
2. Ensure the data from the previous load is cached and available instantly

Is this possible to do? I can provide a plunker if it's necessary.

Comment: please provide plunker

Comment: @RohitShedage Here's the version with hardcoded data: https://embed.plnkr.co/fYSgaaM3X4XZlHwTsGDb/
and dynamic: https://embed.plnkr.co/oN4eFfye0QsPwlzD93yx/